# How to declare ArrayAdapter without initializing it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I'm new to Kotlin, I have two activities, first page calls second page, then second page finishes and saves data to a table. First activity has a listview getting populated from the same table. I figured the way to do it might be to override the onResume and call the arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

However I can't figure out how to move my local arrayAdapter variable to become a global variable.

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe overriding the onActivityResult method? But still not sure if that's the best approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the table is not a database and just a data holder intent, the best practice is to override `onActivityResult`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

also 
you can make your adapter global easily by late initialization

```
lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<YourModel>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it tells me, "One type Argument expected for class...", do I just pass it the same parameters again? Except maybe a nullarray in place of the list?

Comment: @user9333933 the error is happening because ArrayAdapter is generic you need to explicitly set the type  of it you need to pass your model 
for example `lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: For some reason my listview wouldn't update, so I just moved all my code into the onResume method and it works now and i removed the notifydatasetchanged, because I just initialize my adapter in onResume